# When using ExecutorService, are the classes within threadsafe?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

I have an implementation of a Runnable class which contains a Vector of objects that items are removed from one by one and processed.

Using the ExecutorService and creating a newFixedThreadPool with n number of threads, are there n number of instances of the Runnable class? If so, are the classes and the Vector within threadsafe, or would this need to be implemented using synchronized?

Thanks

Comment: A `Runnable` class implementation is not inherently thread safe. The executor just handles creating the threads. You are free to wreck havoc as you wish in your `Runnable`.

Comment: Your question is underspecified. In the most straightforward interpretation of what you said, you are safe, but... If you all the `Runnable`s reference the same `Vector` instance and are doing more than just removing, you are **not** safe. If the objects your `Vector` or `Vector`s contain are not thread-safe, and instances of them are concurrently accessed from different threads, you are **not** safe. `ExecutorService` doesn't matter too much here - many problems that you could hit with manually starting some `Thread`s will also be present when you are using executors and thread pools.

Comment: There are as many number of instances of the runnable as **you** do `new MyRunnableThing`. Runnables can run many times and in parallel if you tell the executor to do so. `Runnable` is just an `interface` - there is no thread magic attached to it. You can use it like every other java object.

Comment: Sorry @DimitarDimitrov I should have specified, the vector is indeed passed in the Runnable constructor as an argument, therefore is shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have stated, if you are sharing your Vector across Runnables, then it is not threadsafe.  To be threadsafe, you should use either bound queue (like BlockingQueue) or unbound queue (like ConcurrentLinkedQueue) instead of Vector.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `newFixedThreadPool` so it means, at any point max `n` threads are active. If you start `n` Runnables and all threads are busy, every additional Runnable will wait until a thread is available.

Your implementation has no shared resources (at least it looks like so) between runnables. In this case you don't need synchronization. But if, for example, you have one instance of vector and multiple instances of your 'workers', in that case you need synchronization.

Comment: Sorry @leshkin I should have specified, the vector is indeed passed in the Runnable constructor as an argument, therefore is shared.

Comment: Ok, in this case you definitely need synchronization.

Comment: synchronization will defeat the purpose of having multiple threads.  I would use threadsafe queues instead of Vector.

Comment: @javagirl look at this class https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html